# Centre align Subview UIview at the centre

Tags: ios, uiview, xcode-storyboard, ios-autolayout

I have following storyboard based design with constraints
[image]

[image]

[image]

I am adding this view to main view as follows

```
 NSArray *nibContents = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CompanyFundView" owner:nil options:nil];
CompanyFundView *view = [nibContents lastObject];
UIWindow* mainWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
UIView *parent = mainWindow.subviews[0];

CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenWidth = screenRect.size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = screenRect.size.height;

view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
[parent addSubview:view];
```

As you can see the view isnt appearing inside the main view and not getting resized , what are the other constraints i need to add ?

Comment: where are you adding the view? viewDidLoad?

Comment: @BJHStudios on a button click

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are adding `NSLayoutConstraint` on a storyboard scene with width and height set to `w:Any h:Any`

I can see you are using `w:Any Regular`

The constraints are specific so it won't scale.

Use specific scene sizes when dealing with specific layout for a targeted device size